# Server Side Action Upon Countdown Complete

Tags: php, mysql, api, daemon, countdown

I've been researching an answer for this and couldn't find a similar question that fits the use case.

I have a vendor building a mobile app / API (php, mysql) for me and their solution seems unstable and unreliable. Looking for a better approach.

The capability would allow a user to set up an instance of a countdown - stored in the database with a start time and end time some time in the future. Once the end time is reached, an action is to be performed.

Currently, the solution is using a daemon on the server that runs every minute to check for all completed end times and perform an action based on the instance of the countdown the user has selected. The problem is, as I mentioned, this is very unreliable. When it's working, it works great. But it often doesn't work.

In the client (the app) when a user hits the countdown screen it checks the start time and end time from the API and starts the countdown at the appropriate time. When the client hits the end time, it makes a call back to the API to check the results of the action and displays it in the client.

So, long story short I'm trying to figure out a more stable alternative to running a daemon on the server to check for end times and triggering an action. Because the client is expecting the action to be completed at the end time, it should be a quick and reliable process. I had considered using the client call to the API as the trigger to run the action but if 40 other clients are watching the same countdown and request to the API at the same time I'm afraid I might run into conflicts.

Thanks in advance for any advice here!

Answer (score 0):

Is the user on the website the whole time? I achieve something similar by getting a start time, converting it to minutes/seconds and then creating a javascript countdown that waits an extra 2 seconds after the time is done (ensures the timer is really over). Then, it makes an ajax call to a php script to complete an action (which returns a `JSON` string.

Saves you server side and it's only ran when the user is there and needs it to.

Comment: Thanks Derek. The problem here is that I need something to run the action on the server before the call from the client side because there will be multiple clients accessing the same countdown at the same time. Almost like I need a watcher on the server side.